# Polymer button/text gets bolded when navigating away and then back

Tags: javascript, html, css, polymer

So I notice this behavior but I don't understand how to prevent it from happening:

I have a `paper-button` or `paper-fab`, like the button "Contact" in the top right of the following image: [image]

I click on it (in google chrome, Windows 7), then navigate away. When I come back, for `paper-button`, the text inside is bolded (and then become normal when I click on it again). For `paper-fab`, the background color of the button changes to a darker shade. I attached an image below for `paper-button` after navigating back: [image]

Just click on your button, Alt-Tab away to another program, and then Alt-Tab back to Chrome

Please comment below if you have been able to see/recreate this

Comment: Please create a demo of your problem so we can see.

Comment: yeah I just added a demo

Comment: unable to replicate.

Comment: @atinder I added all the steps that I did

Comment: Not able to replicate it.

Answer (score 0):

inspecting the actual contact part of the paper-material when tabbing shows that:

```
.keyboard-focus.paper-button {
font-weight: bold
}
```

is being set, maybe you can target this and set it to normal?

Comment: I saw this but it's tricky to do since I'm dealing with Shadow DOM from outside

Comment: Try using the ::shadow psudeo selector to style through the shadow dom